# php sql update join

Tags: php, mysql, join

Just learning about sql joins and things, and I have a question.

Can you JOIN on an update query? Or is it only for select ones. Because I have this code;

```
$five_ago = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$now - 5 mins"));

$sql_result23 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usersonline WHERE timestamp < '$five_ago'", $db);
while ($rs23 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result23)) { 
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET status='gone' WHERE id ='$rs23[userID]'"); 
}
```

It picks out from the `usersonline` table all the ones that are older than 5 minutes, then finds them in the `users` table and updates their record.

I'm not a JOIN wizard or anything but i think a join would simplify that. 
Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `IN`:

```
UPDATE users 
SET status='gone' 
WHERE id IN 
      ( SELECT userID 
        FROM usersonline 
        WHERE timestamp < '$five_ago'
      )
```

Using `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE users 
  JOIN usersonline 
    ON usersonline.userID = users.id
SET users.status='gone' 
WHERE usersonline.timestamp < '$five_ago'
```

Using `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE users 
SET status='gone' 
WHERE EXISTS  
      ( SELECT *
        FROM usersonline 
        WHERE timestamp < '$five_ago'
          AND userID = users.id
      )
```

---

You could also skip the `5 minutes ago` calculations in PHP and let the MySQL engine do that work, with:

```
WHERE timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Comment: Legit, you could even take it one step further and calculate the timestamp diff at the mysql layer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can JOIN in an `UPDATE` statement, but I would probably use the `IN ()` subquery as suggested elsewhere, as I find the syntax more straightforward than the awkward `JOIN` below:

```
UPDATE users 
  JOIN usersonline ON users.id = usersonline.userid
  SET users.status='gone'
WHERE usersonline.timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

Note also the use of MySQL's own [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) so you don't have to handle that in PHP beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this??

```
UPDATE users, usersonline 
SET users.status='gone' 
WHERE users.id ='$rs23[userID]' 
AND usersonline.timestamp < '$five_ago';
```

Should work well.

Answer (score 0):

I will introduce you to the command IN.

Example :

```
WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

What you gonna do here ? First. Create an array.

```
$five_ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$now - 5 mins"));

$Array = array();

$sql_result23 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `usersonline` WHERE `timestamp` < "'.$five_ago.'"', $db);
while ($rs23 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result23)){ 
    $Array[] = $rs23['userID'];
}

mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `status`= "gone" WHERE `id` IN ('.join(',', $Array).')');
```

Comment: So, two queries with a PHP `.join()` in between, is faster than one query with `JOIN`? Where do you base that claim?

Comment: Oups, no sorry. Your right I am very lost here lol ! I wanted to say will be faster then running an UPDATE for each user... I was lost in my mind.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, your way is still faster (only 2 queries) than the original `while` loop (n+1 queries).

Comment: Yes, this is it. Sorry. But I didn't know about the UPDATE join, I will update some of my queries :P You teached something new to me today.